# MATLAB getenv unable to find some linux environment variables

Tags: linux, matlab, shell, environment-variables

I have a minor problem -- the workaround is trivial, but I wanted to learn why the problem exists at all. I have some environment variables set in .bashrc:

```
export FREESURFER_HOME=/usr/local/freesurfer
```

In my startup.m file, I tried to set the variable:

```
freesurfer_home=getenv('FREESURFER_HOME');
```

However, this call to getenv returns an empty character array. Calls to getenv within MATLAB return some environment variables (e.g., getenv('HOME')) but not others. I can see which environment variables are visible to MATLAB from the following line:

```
 map = java.lang.System.getenv();
```

I can also confirm the missing values are visible, at least within the shell, using any of

```
export
env
printenv
```

Is there an explanation for this discrepancy?

Comment: Do you launch Matlab from the shell or from some start-menu or so? In the latter case, `.bashrc` might not be called ...

Comment: I'm not on Linux to test it, but what if you set the environment variable inside your `.profile`/`.bash_profile` config file instead?

Comment: its really odd, I am calling a bash script and defining the envvariable from the bash script and THEN I call the matlab script and it still doesn't find it. Isn't that odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check process tree with [system](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/system.html) and [ps f](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) command in Matlab, you will see that it actually launches `sh` and executes there your command. I don't have Matlab, the same thing with Octave.

```
octave:1> system("ps f")
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2520 pts/0    Ss     0:00 bash
 2580 pts/0    Sl+    0:02  \_ octave
 2885 pts/0    S+     0:00      \_ sh -c ps f
 2886 pts/0    R+     0:00          \_ ps f
ans = 0
```

In this case variables set in `.bashrc` are available through [getenv](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/getenv.html) as I launch octave from bash. But when launching Matlab from menu launcher, the situation is different:

```
octave:1> system("ps f")
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3400 pts/2    Ssl+   0:01 /usr/bin/octave
 3444 pts/2    S+     0:00  \_ sh -c ps f
 3445 pts/2    R+     0:00      \_ ps f
```

bash has not been executed and exports from `.bashrc` are not set.

Comment: its really odd, I am calling a bash script and defining the envvariable from the bash script and THEN I call the matlab script and it still doesn't find it. Isn't that odd?

Comment: It depends how do you call a shell script, how do you define a variable there and then how you call Matlab script afterwards.